# How to show only the monthly ticks in the x axis when using DataFrame.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, visualization

I am plotting daily data directly using the pandas DataFrame plotting method as shown below.

```py
gna_plot[['Forecast', 'Off', 'Ans']].plot(xticks=gna_plot.index, figsize=(16, 8), subplots=True)
```

If I use this method then I get something like this in the plot which is obviously very messy. I only want to show the first or last date of every month. How can I show just those 12 xticks in this plot?

[image]

Comment: To clarify: Are you looking to _reduce the number_ of xticks, or just _label fewer_ of the existing ticks?

Comment: Label fewer of the existing ticks so that I can show one for each month.

Comment: For a start - convert your string index into a datetime index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


 ax = plt.gca()
 # start by your date and then your data
 ax.plot(region['Date'],region["temperature(°C)"]) # daily data
 # You can change the step of range() as you prefer (now, it selects each third month) 
 ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=range(1,12,3)))
 # you can change the format of the label (now it is 2016-Jan)  
 ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b'))
    
 plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90) 
 plt.show()
```

You can read more [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html).
[image]

You have another, more flexible option which is `plotly`:

```
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# data  where the index is the date
fig = px.line(df_temp, x=df_temp.index, y=df_temp.columns[2:5])

# Show plot 
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
fig.show()
```

You have a slider to zoom in and zoom out by dates like that:
[image]

For instance, here I zoomed in to see how temperature behaves during this interval:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The crucial step is to convert the x axis data to datetime.

Here is an example using COVID data from ourworldindata.org.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

covidData = pd.read_csv('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv')

covidData.date = pd.to_datetime(covidData.date)  # This is the datetime conversion.

covidDataDenmark = covidData[covidData.location=='Denmark']  # Selecting one country.

covidDataDenmark.plot(x='date', y='new_cases_smoothed_per_million')
```

[Pandas plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8uyE.png)

Alternatively, Matplotlib is a good choice. In this case, rotate the `xticks` by 45 degrees for better readability.

```
plt.plot(covidDataDenmark.date, covidDataDenmark.new_cases_smoothed_per_million)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[Matplotlib plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEmE7.png)