# drawing bars for time series with years as bins in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, time-series, plotly, bar-chart

so i have data as readings recorded as monthly averages over time. I have already drawn it but the problem is the graph is kinda messed up and the X axis is unreadable, i have been trying for two days to draw it without a success, any help would be appreciated. i was able to get the image i want from plotly using the exact same code just instead drawing using "iplot" instead of "plot", you can see the result in the second image. but the problem is that i have no way of exporting it as SVG, besides i really like matplotlib so i want to use it. the code is at the end, i should also note that all the commented out lines are failed attempts.

here is the graph that i get:
[image: This is the image i get]

and this is the image i want:
[image: This is the kind of image i want]

lastly here is the code:

```
fig, ax= plt.subplots(1,1)
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
ax=hist.count().plot(kind='bar',  color='brown',  legend=True)
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator(10))
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("\n%Y"))
# plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0, ha="center")
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y"))
# fig.autofmt_xdate()
# plt.xticks(hist['Date'], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

This is the previous state of the data (grouped by WellCode):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDSWD.png)

this is after a group them annually to basically make a histogram for the occurrence distribution:

```
{Timestamp('1888-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 1,
 Timestamp('1889-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 1,
Timestamp('1890-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 1,
Timestamp('1891-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 1,
Timestamp('1892-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 1,
....................
Timestamp('2000-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 411670,
Timestamp('2001-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 423100,
Timestamp('2002-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 434910,
Timestamp('2003-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 447776,
Timestamp('2004-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 460983,
Timestamp('2005-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 475415,
Timestamp('2006-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 490284,
Timestamp('2007-12-31 00:00:00', freq='A-DEC'): 505549}
```

Comment: If I understand you well, you need to draw the same plot but in matplotlib instead of plotly. I  answered here but in a monthly basis, you can reuse it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271229/16733101

Comment: In such cases, it is better to have sample data to avoid discrepancies in responses. Also, if SVG output is needed, do you need suggestions for other libraries such as Plotly?

Comment: thank you for the reply, its your code works for line graph but for bar graph it has no effect. I wanted to attach the resulting photo but i couldn't do it for a comment.

Comment: I want to ask you whether you want to plot your data with histogram or with bars?

Comment: i want to draw it with histogram but i couldn't do it, thats why i grouped them outside using groupby and count and then drew them using bars, if its possible to do it directly by histogram, that would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this small data and you want to get the histogram to this data as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst = ['2010-01-01','2011-01-01','2011-01-01','2012-01-01','2012-01-01','2012-01-01',
       '2013-01-01','2013-01-01','2013-01-01','2013-01-01','2014-01-01','2014-01-01',
       '2014-01-01','2015-01-01','2015-01-01','2015-01-01','2016-01-01','2016-01-01',
       '2017-01-01','2018-01-01','2019-01-01']

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Date'])

plt.hist(df["Date"]) # daily data

plt.show()
```

[image]

**To solve this problem, you should convert your date column from `str` to `datetime` and see how the plot looks like:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Date'])

df["Date"] =pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])  # add this line before plotting

plt.hist(df["Date"]) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to save your histogram plot in .svg format, you should add this line directly after the plot in this way:

```
plt.hist(df["Date"]) 
plt.savefig("test.svg")   # add your line directly after plot.hist()
plt.show()
```

**Final remark:** now you can use the additional settings smoothly to set up the x-axis as you prefer, this is an example:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(2)) # show every 2 years on the x-axis 
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b'))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, it seems that worked just fine. i appreciate it.